# Build a program that will help the company store and analyze sales data

Tags: python

I have to write a program that writes a file for a company and analyzes the sales data.

- request_countryname function has to validate the user's input is at least 2 characters long
- request_sales function has to accept 2 parameters (product and country), request the user for input on the total sales for each product of that country, and validate that the amount is numeric and non negative
- request_data function will iteratively request country names from the user using the above functions and will ask if the user wants to add another country. Once the user is finished, the program will display how many records were added to the file. The program will write a file name (sales_data.txt)
- analyze_data function will calculate the average sales per country for each type of product, total amount of sales for each product type, and total amount of sales

I am having trouble with the analyze_data function. I keep getting an error saying some of my variable from the request_data function are undefined. I believe this is happening because these variables (such as software_accumulator) are defined locally, not globally. I tried calling the request_data function at the beginning of my analyze_data function to call the information I wrote in the file, but I am still getting an error. I am also not sure if I correctly used accumulators to calculate the totals for each product type.

How do I fix this?

```
#Request country name from user
#Country name must be at least 2 characters long 
def request_countryname():
    
    character_length = 2             
    while True: 
        country = input("Please enter the country's name: ")   
        if len(country) < character_length or not country.isalpha():
            print("Name must be at least 2 characters.")
        else:
            return country 


#Request total sales for each product type for the user's country
#Input must be numeric and non negative
def request_sales(product, country_name):
    
    flag = -1
    while flag < 0: 
        sales = input("Please enter the total sales for " + product + " in " + country_name + ": $ ")
        try:
           sales = float(sales)
        except ValueError:
            print("Amount must be numeric")
        else: 
            if sales < 0 :
                print("Amount must be numeric and and non-negative. ")
            else:
                flag = 1
    return sales 

 
    
#Iteratively requests country names from the user and asks for totals
#Once the user finishes inputting countries, program will store data to a file 
#Program will display total number of records added 
def request_data(sales_data):
    
    sales_data = open(sales_data, "w")
    count = 0
    software_accumulator = 0
    hardware_accumulator = 0
    accessories_accumulator = 0
    
    again = "y"
    while again == "y" or again == "Y":
            country_name = request_countryname()
            software = request_sales("software", country_name)
            hardware = request_sales("hardware", country_name)
            accessories = request_sales("accessories", country_name)

            #Write data to file 
            sales_data.write(country_name + '/n')
            sales_data.write(software + '/n')
            sales_data.write(hardware + '/n')
            sales_data.write(accessories + '/n')
            
            count += 1   
            software_accumulator += software 
            hardware_accumulator += hardware
            accessories_accumulator += accessories
            
           
            #Request country names from user
            again = input("Do you want to add another country? (Enter y/Y for Yes: ")
           
            #Displays total number of records added 
            print(count, " record(s) successfully added to file")
            
            
    sales_data.close()
    
           
#Calculates and displays information 
def analyze_data(sales_data):
    
    sales_data = open(sales_data, "r")
    sales_data = request_data(sales_data)
    
    #Calculates total software of all country inputs 
    total_software = software_accumulator  
    
    #Calculates total hardware of all country inputs
    total_hardware = hardware_accumulator
    
    #Calculates total accessories of all country inputs
    total_accessories =  accessories_accumulator
    
    #Calcuates average software
    average_software = total_software / count
    
    #Calcuates average hardware
    average_hardware = total_hardware / count
    
    #Calcuates average accessories
    average_accessories = total_accessories / count

    #Calculates total sales 
    total_sales = total_software + total_hardware + total_accessories
        
    #Prints and displays calculations 
    print("----------------------------")
    print()
    print("Average software sales per country: $ ", format(average_software, ',.2f'))
    print("Average hardware sales per country: $ ", format(average_hardware, ',.2f'))
    print("Average accessories sales per country: $ ", format(average_accessories, ',.2f'))

    print()
    print("Total software sales: $ ", format(total_software, ',.2f'))
    print("Total hardware sales: $ ", format(total_hardware, ',.2f'))
    print("Total accessories sales: $ ", format(total_accessories, ',.2f'))

    print()
    print("Total sales: $ ", format(total_sales, ',.2f'))

#Defines main function
def main():    
    request_data("sales_data.txt")    
    analyze_data("sales_data.txt")
    
#Calls main function     
main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in your hunch it has to do with the scope the variable are in, pay attention to where you define your variables, once you exit a function all variables in that functions scope will be gone. Don't use global variables, but return values you need from a function.

I suggest using an IDE to develop in as well, they will tell you when you are accessing a variable that is not in scope (ie not defined) - PyCharm or VSCode are both highly accessible

IDE says function isn't returning value
[image]

IDE says variable not defined
[image]